# bazel.rc seems take no effect when build tensorflow-serving r1.10 or r1.11

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I am building tensorflow-serving r1.10; since my centos7 default python version is 2.7.13 and I want to build with python3.6,  so I changed the  PYTHON_BIN_PATH in tools/bazel.rc like this.[The python3.6 env is installed with pyenv]

```
build --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH="/home/pyenv/.pyenv/versions/tensorflow-serving/bin/python"
build --define PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/home/pyenv/.pyenv/versions/tensorflow-serving/bin/python
```

---

It had been worked when I build tensorflow-serving r 1.9 before. but now, It does not work,  so it is the problem with tensorflow-serving r1.11

```
    ERROR: /home/pyenv/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pyenv/73f8d77da757234474f166b154bb24f7/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:581:1: Executing genrule @org_tensorflow//tensorflow:tensorflow_python_api_gen failed (Exit 1): bash failed: error executing command 
      (cd /home/pyenv/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pyenv/73f8d77da757234474f166b154bb24f7/execroot/tf_serving && \
      exec env - \
        PATH=/home/pyenv/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:/home/pyenv/.pyenv/shims:/home/pyenv/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/ffmpeg/bin/:/opt/jdk1.8.0_112/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/pyenv/.local/bin:/home/pyenv/bin \
      /bin/bash -c 'source external/bazel_tools/tools/genrule/genrule-setup.sh; bazel-out/host/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api --root_init_template=external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/api_template.__init__.py --apidir=bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow --apiname=tensorflow --apiversion=2 --package=tensorflow.python --output_package=tensorflow bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/app/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/bitwise/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/compat/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/data/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/debugging/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/distributions/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/distributions/bijectors/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/dtypes/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/errors/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/feature_column/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/gfile/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/graph_util/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/image/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/io/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/initializers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/activations/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/applications/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/applications/densenet/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/applications/inception_resnet_v2/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/applications/inception_v3/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/applications/mobilenet/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/applications/nasnet/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/applications/resnet50/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/applications/vgg16/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/applications/vgg19/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/applications/xception/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/backend/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/callbacks/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/constraints/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/datasets/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/datasets/boston_housing/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/datasets/cifar10/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/datasets/cifar100/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/datasets/fashion_mnist/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/datasets/imdb/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/datasets/mnist/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/datasets/reuters/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/estimator/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/initializers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/layers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/losses/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/metrics/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/models/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/optimizers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/preprocessing/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/preprocessing/image/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/preprocessing/sequence/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/preprocessing/text/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/regularizers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/utils/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/wrappers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/layers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/linalg/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/logging/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/losses/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/manip/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/math/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/metrics/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/nn/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/nn/rnn_cell/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/profiler/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python_io/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/quantization/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/resource_loader/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/strings/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/saved_model/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/saved_model/builder/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/saved_model/constants/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/saved_model/loader/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/saved_model/main_op/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/saved_model/signature_constants/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/saved_model/signature_def_utils/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/saved_model/tag_constants/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/saved_model/utils/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/sets/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/sparse/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/spectral/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/summary/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/sysconfig/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/test/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/train/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/train/queue_runner/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/user_ops/__init__.py')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/pyenv/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pyenv/73f8d77da757234474f166b154bb24f7/execroot/tf_serving/bazel-out/host/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/api/generator/create_python_api.py", line 27, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.tools.api.generator import doc_srcs
      File "/home/pyenv/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pyenv/73f8d77da757234474f166b154bb24f7/execroot/tf_serving/bazel-out/host/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
      File "/home/pyenv/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pyenv/73f8d77da757234474f166b154bb24f7/execroot/tf_serving/bazel-out/host/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
        raise ImportError(msg)
    ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/pyenv/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pyenv/73f8d77da757234474f166b154bb24f7/execroot/tf_serving/bazel-out/host/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
      File "/home/pyenv/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pyenv/73f8d77da757234474f166b154bb24f7/execroot/tf_serving/bazel-out/host/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
      File "/home/pyenv/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pyenv/73f8d77da757234474f166b154bb24f7/execroot/tf_serving/bazel-out/host/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
        _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
    ImportError: /home/pyenv/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pyenv/73f8d77da757234474f166b154bb24f7/execroot/tf_serving/bazel-out/host/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: _Py_FalseStruct
```

There even no PYTHON_BIN_PATH in the exec command.

I know tensorflow-serving r1.10 should build with bazel0.15 +, So what happend here? how do I change bazel.rc to specify my python path ?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without a [minimal, complete, and veriafiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Perhaps bazel isn't picking up on your workspace for some reason?

One thing you can try is using a .bazelrc file instead:

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/best-practices.html#bazelrc

Comment: I found that it is ok to  do
 " bazel build ...    tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server"
but failed to do
"bazel build ...    tensorflow_serving/..."

Comment: That makes sense since modelserver is a c++ project. Does it work if you just inline your arguments?

Comment: No, If I build with "bazel build ... tensorflow_serving/..." and inline argument "PYTHON_BIN_PATH", It helped nothing either. The error message just like mentioned before.